# asp.net MVC 4 0x80070005 - Javascript runtime error: access denied

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having problems with regards starting up a ASP.NET MVC 4. An internet application. Once I start the app, image below will display so as I clicked Continue I will proceed and display the page as it is but as I navigate through the page, error still pops up. How can I fix this problem? Any idea?

I'm running windows 8. Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. Hope you can help me out with this. I really want to learn how to do things in ASP.NET. I'm new to this one anyway. Thanks.

[image: error]

[image: scripts]

And above is shown the scripts that the IDE generated for me. As for my Internet Explorer security settings.. Internet is medium-high, Local Intranet is Medium-low, Trusted Sites is Medium and Restricted Sites is High

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so which version? Do you *need* to use modernizer?

Comment: What are the security settings for Internet Explorer? What is line 813 in Modernizer's source code? That's the place to start.

Comment: Well actually the IDE itself generated all the files for me, and so it uses jquery-1.8.2 and all the other scripts. Edited my post.

Comment: Have you checked if your app has rights to access the network? Open the appxmanifest and check the capability tab.

Comment: It's running fine in google chrome but in IE it does show up that message.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `locaStorage` or `sessionStorage`? If yes that might be the reason for that.
If you are using them, then try to use it in InPrivate browsing in IE, it will work.
Or Go to `InternetOptions -> Security` and `uncheck EnableProtectedMode` and then try to run.

**UPDATE**:

Uncheck EnableProtectedMode for "**Local Intranet**" if it is in intranet.